# Equation in LP files using power sign for cplex

Tags: cplex

Im trying to solve a Linear Programming problem in cplex using an lp format file, including one equation like this:

DiscCflow = (Cashflow / ((1+y)^(year))

Anyone knows how to write it in a way to be read and solved using cplex?

Thanks

Susete

Comment: Be careful because if you have an expression in your model that includes a variable raised to a power then your model will not be linear. Cplex can handle some nonlinear terms like quadratics, but some other solvers cannot. Alex's answer only has constants in the power term, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

The [zoo story](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) can be written in OPL CPLEX

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

dexpr float Cashflow=costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
int year=3;
float y=0.01;

dexpr float DiscCflow = Cashflow / ((1+y)^(year));
 
minimize
 DiscCflow;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```